# How to create attribute with class restrictions

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, attributeusage

In C# there is a attribute called `AttributeUsage`, if you want to set this attribute to a class it automatically detects if the class is derived from the Attribute class and if not it will throw an error.

How can I create such restrictions?

I want to create an attribute which should only be available/settable on a specific class.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/writing-custom-attributes#applying-the-attributeusageattribute

Comment: Just look up the documentation for [AttributeUsage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attributeusageattribute.-ctor) which has an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible via attributes `AttributeUsage` alone, but can be achieved in other way.

`AttributeUsage` has [`ValidOn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attributeusageattribute.validon?view=netframework-4.8#System_AttributeUsageAttribute_ValidOn) property, that is of [`AttributeTarget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/writing-custom-attributes#applying-the-attributeusageattribute) type. It lets you specify that it's valid only on `class`, but not type of this class.

So, why `AttributeUsage` only works on classes that derive from `Attribute`? It's a compiler rule [CS0641](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0641)

> 'attribute' : attribute is only valid on classes derived from System.Attribute
>
> An attribute was used that can only be used on a class that derives from **System.Attribute**.

It's not part of `AttributeUsage` itself.

If you want to achieve something like this, you will need to write your own Roslyn analyzer, that will check it for you. There are few tutorials on how to do write one, i.e. [official one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix) or [this](https://roslyn-analyzers.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to-start.html)), I also suggest to look at [`roslyn-analyzers`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers) code, `CS0641` is not there, since it's a compiler error, not an analyzer, but you can get quite a lot of references here.

I hope it helps you, wish you good luck!